# Uninstall and install grows the reported size of the application

Tags: wix

I've written an installer in WiX; and it works very well. However, I've having a minor issue where the "reported" size of the installer seems to be growing with each subsequent installation.

Steps

1. Install application
2. Goto 'Control Panel' select 'Program and Features', find application and look at Size.
3. Uninstall applicaiton
4. Install applicaiton
5. Go back to 'Control Panel', select 'Program and Features', find applicaiton and look at Size again (it's grown roughly by the size of the installer).

Does anyone have any ideas how I stop the growth between installs? Or if this is by design?

Comment: I was also having a similar issue and asked a question on SO. Someone tried to answer it but I am not sure if its the way it has to be. [link to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10635371/1140783)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do your components have `Permanent` set to "yes"?  These components are preserved even after uninstall.  Look also for `RemoveOnuninstall` attributes.

Each program may or may not provide [its own size information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/09/178342.aspx) to Windows.  WiX based programs typically do not and let Windows guess.  (Search for `ARPSIZE` in your project to learn whether you do.) Consequently, Windows does not necessarily notice all of the files, but typically all the size reported is actually taken and worth researching via the file system.  It may include files *generated* by your program somewhere under `Program Files`.

This size does not include space taken by the [Windows Installer Cache](http://makemsi-manual.dennisbareis.com/caching.htm).  This is good to know about, too, as it is often as big as the installed software itself.  The MSI is cached primarily to support easier uninstallation.

For a one-time cleanup of program related disk space you can use the [Windows Cleanup utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438651/).

Comment: OK, running the Windows Cleanup utility and then uninstalling my installer seems to have fixed it. I've reinstalled several times and the file size isn't going up. Anyone got any ideas what I could have done to cause this?

Comment: @MartinClarke - When you say uninstall + install, do you mean the exact same build of the product, or minor upgrades (rebuilt MSI)?  And, does "uninstalling the installer" simply mean the uninstallation of your product?  Anyway, if I were in your shoes, I'd probably let it be now until the next occurrence (you may then spot what kind of build action triggers it), then search for unexpected mass via the file system, and then try to explain its growth mainly by looking at custom action logic in your WiX.

Comment: its pre-release, so its typically the same product, different version numbers. Yes, uninstalling my installer means that. Thanks for your advice.